# How can I intent a unique key when InfoWindowClick was click in google maps V2 android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, infowindow

I want to intent two unique keys that are needed by the other activity to operate successfully, but I don't know how to intent the two unique keys when it comes to infowindowclick in markers. Is there a way that I can pass the data properly instead of adding those keys to the snippet? Please take a look at my code below.

```
// I am getting the values of the store here including the storeID
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(latLng);
for (DocumentSnapshot storeDS: queryDocumentSnapshots){
    StoreDetailsModel detailsModel = storeDS.toObject(StoreDetailsModel.class);
    GeoPoint storeAddress = detailsModel.getStoreLocation();
    double LatitudeData = storeAddress.getLatitude();
    double LongitudeData = storeAddress.getLongitude();
    final LatLng SlatLng = new LatLng(LatitudeData, LongitudeData);

    if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLng, SlatLng) < 35000){
        String storeID = detailsModel.getStoreID();
        String storeName = detailsModel.getStoreName();
        String storeClass = detailsModel.getStoreClassification();
        HashMap storeImg = detailsModel.getStoreImage();
        String image = storeImg.get("profile").toString();

        addCustomMarkerFromURL(SlatLng, image, storeName, storeClass, mMap, storeID, uid);
        builder.include(SlatLng);
    }
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 200);
mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MapFragment.this);


...


//Then here is the method for infoWindowClick Listener
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StoreDetailsActivity.class)

        //Here I have a trouble finding a way to pass the data for the storeID and buyerID

        //intent.putExtra("storeID", storeID);
        //intent.putExtra("buyerID", buyerID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**addCustomMarkerFromURL() Method:**

```
private void addCustomMarkerFromURL(final LatLng slatLng, String image, final String storeName, final String storeClass, final GoogleMap mMap, final String storeID, final String uid) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(image).fitCenter()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @androidx.annotation.Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
//                        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleInfoWindowAdapter(getActivity(), storeID, uid));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(slatLng)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(getActivity(), resource, storeName))).title(storeClass));
                    }
                });
    }
```

**getMarkerBitmapFromView() Method**

```
private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(FragmentActivity activity, Bitmap resource, String storeName) {
        View view = ((LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.bitmap_google_marker_layout_item, null);

        TextView txt_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txt_name.setText(storeName);

        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView image = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.store_profile_image);
        image.setImageBitmap(resource);
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tag instead of snippet.

creat a class that has 2 properties "storeId" n "buyerId"

```
public class MyRefId {
    private int storeID;
    private int buyerID;

    public MyRefId(int storeID, int buyerID) {
        this.storeID = storeID;
        this.buyerID = buyerID;
    }

    public int getStoreID() {
        return storeID;
    }

    public void setStoreID(int storeID) {
        this.storeID = storeID;
    }

    public int getBuyerID() {
        return buyerID;
    }

    public void setBuyerID(int buyerID) {
        this.buyerID = buyerID;
    }
}
```

---

in addCustomMarkerFromURL()

```
private void addCustomMarkerFromURL(final LatLng slatLng, String image, final String storeName, final String storeClass, final GoogleMap mMap, final String storeID, final String uid) {
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(image).fitCenter()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @androidx.annotation.Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                     // to make it clear for you I do it this way
                     // start by new MarkerOption()
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                                 .position(slatLng) 
                                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                                   getMarkerBitmapFromView(getActivity(), resource, storeName))).title(storeClass);

                    // when you call mMap.addMarker(markerOptions) a new 
                    // marker will be added to the map
                    // this method also return those marker
                    // to set tag u can do sth like:
                       Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                       marker.setTag(new MyRefId(storID,uid));

                   // or
                   // mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setTag(new MyRefId(storID,uid));
                }
            });
}
```

Then here is the method for infoWindowClick Listener

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        // get marker tag
        MyRefId refId = (MyRefId) marker.getTag();

        if(refId != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StoreDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("storeID", refId.getStoreID());
            intent.putExtra("buyerID", refId.getBuyerID());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Can you please show this to me in Android studio way? Thank you!

Comment: can you show me the code of this function: `addCustomMarkerFromURL()`, where the mMap.addMarker() is called?

Comment: I had included the methods for creating the custom marker.

Comment: Also I have a question about using the marker. How should I instantiate it if I had many data in database? Is it okay to instantiate only one variable of marker?

Comment: I think it's okay to instantiate many markers. when you call mMap.addMarker(markerOptions), this method will instantiate a new marker and add it to the map

Comment: I confused about the data type of storeId and buyerId. You could change it to String